# Why is there a preceding \ufeff in the file read?

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to save a text into a document and tried to read text from the document. It turns out that I have a preceding `\ufeff` in the output. I am primarily confused about why this happens. (Here is the REPL, if this isn't clear enough.)

```
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> open("text.txt")
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='text.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp65001'>
>>> open("text.txt").read()
'\ufeff1234'
>>>
```

Comment: it's a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 0):

you should change default encoding from `cp65001` to `utf-8-sig`

replace this:

```py
open("text.txt")
```

with this:

```py
open("text.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```